# j2me delete record from recordstore

Tags: java-me, rms, recordstore

Problem: 
unable to use `deleteRecord()` properly

Background:
I have a simple j2me application where I add various strings to the record store and try to manipulate the contents of the record store. I add records on one screen and then read them on another. I can move back and forth with these screens

Problem description in detail:
For example I add "abc" (recordID is 1) , "def" ( id is 2) and "ghi" ( id is 3).
When I delete these records in the order `rs.deleteRecord(3),rs.deleteRecord(2),rs.deleteRecord(1)` everything works like it is supposed to.

When I try any other order I get **"Msg: javax.microedition.rms.InvalidRecordIDException"**
Also when I try to read the other records after this deletion there is no output.

I want to be able remove the records in any order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I I read [the documentaton](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#deleteRecord(int)) correctly, then this *should* not happen. Did you try enumerating the records after each `deleteRecord()` call to see which ones are left (content **and** id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. But after carefully reading the api class and this method I found a line written in the explanation that "The record is deleted from the record store. The recordId for this record is NOT reused."
Hence to update and add a specific data at the same record number is not possible in recordstore!
Therefore you either need to use Record enumeration technique or use a class with the required fields you want to store , convert it into ByteArray and then store the ByteArray in a record store.
Hope this would help you and others.

Answer (score 4):

Open `RecordStore` that name is rs...
And then...

```
RecordEnumeration re=null;
try {
  re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, true);
} catch (RecordStoreNotOpenException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

int rid=0;

try {
  while (re.hasNextElement()) {
    rid=re.nextRecordId();
    try {
      rs.deleteRecord(rid);
    } catch (RecordStoreNotOpenException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidRecordIDException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RecordStoreException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
} catch (InvalidRecordIDException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```